# Return NULL when no matching records are found

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I'm passing an employee number to a function and getting back the Joined Date.

I want this to return NULL when no matching records found; in my case it is just returning blank or an empty row;

```
get_join_date(in_emp_no)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_join_date(in_emp_no) RETURN DATE IS
  v_join_date DATE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT joined_date
    INTO v_date
    FROM employee
    WHERE employee_number = in_emp_no
          AND type = in_type;

    IF v_join_date IS NOT NULL        THEN
      v_join_date := v_date;
    ELSE
      v_join_date = NULL;
    END IF;

    RETURN v_join_date;
  END;
```

Comment: Running select each time you want to get a data is not the best idea. Create collection, populate it and then get the value from the collection. Collection are session level based so you will have access to it from anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to return either the one existing value or null, you can simply use an aggregate function, e.g. MIN, for that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_join_date( in_emp_no) RETURN DATE
IS
  v_join_DATE DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT MIN(JOINED_DATE)
    INTO v_join_DATE 
    FROM employee
   WHERE employee_number = in_emp_no
     AND TYPE=in_type;
  return v_join_DATE;
end
```

Answer (score 5):

If no matching records are found then a NO_DATA_FOUND exception will be raised; you have to capture this exception and return something.

You're also checking whether `v_join_date` is null and then assigning a null value to it if it is null; there's no need to do this.

```
create or replace function get_join_date( 
      Pemp_no in number
     ) return date is

   l_join_date date;

begin

   select joined_date into l_join_date 
     from employee
    where employee_number = Pemp_no
      and type = in_type;

   return l_join_date;

exception when no_data_found then
   return null;

end;
```

Other errors include:

1. You're selecting into `v_date` but you declared your variable as `v_join_date`
2. There's no semi-colon after your `end` statement.
3. There's no semi-colon after your `endif` statement.
4. `endif` is two words, this should be `end if;`
5. You're not declaring the datatype of the parameter `in_emp_no` you need to (but not the length), for instance `... function get_join_date ( Pemp_no number ) ...`